# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Reply already submitted -- Simple way to send multiple data from native to dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I followed the docs to integerate a native libarary into flutter. https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-java-tab.
Every things working when I use one method channel as in the mentioned docs. But as I Call `result.success();` multiple times flutter is giving expection.

Native Code of Android.

```
package com.example.batterylevel;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel;
import android.content.ContextWrapper;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Build.VERSION;
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
    private static final String CHANNEL = "samples.flutter.dev/battery";
    @Override
    public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
        super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine);
        new MethodChannel(flutterEngine.getDartExecutor().getBinaryMessenger(), CHANNEL)
                .setMethodCallHandler(
                        (call, result) -> {
                            if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
                                int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

                                if (batteryLevel != -1) {

                                    result.success(batteryLevel);
                                } else {
                                    result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
                                }
                            }
                            if(call.method.equals("getPluginData")){
                                String pluginData = getPluginData();
                                result.success(pluginData);

//                                if (batteryLevel != -1) {
//
//                                    result.success(batteryLevel);
//                                } else {
//                                    result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
//                                }
                            }
//
                            else {
                                result.notImplemented();
                            }
                        }
                );
    }
    private int getBatteryLevel() {
        int batteryLevel = -1;
        if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
            batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
        } else {
            Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).
                    registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            batteryLevel = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100) /
                    intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
        }

        return batteryLevel;
    }

    private String getPluginData(){
        return "This is the plugin Data";
    }
}
```

Flutter Dart Code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  static const platform = MethodChannel('samples.flutter.dev/battery');
  String _batteryLevel = 'Unknown battery level.';
  String _pluginData = 'Unknow Plugin Data';
  Future<void> _getBatteryLevel() async {
    String batteryLevel;
    try {
      final int result = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel');
      batteryLevel = 'Battery level at $result % .';
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      batteryLevel = "Failed to get battery level: '${e.message}'.";
    }

    setState(() {
      _batteryLevel = batteryLevel;
    });
  }

  Future<void> _getPluginData() async {
     String pluginData;
    try {
      final String result = await platform.invokeMethod('getPluginData');
      pluginData = 'Plugin Data at $result % .';
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      pluginData = "Failed to get Plugin Data: '${e.message}'.";
    }

    setState(() {
      _pluginData = pluginData;
    });

  }

  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
    _getBatteryLevel();
    _getPluginData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
            ),
            Text(_batteryLevel),
            Text(_pluginData),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Put your multiple values into a `HashMap` and return the map in `result.success()`. At the Dart end you'll get a `Map<String, dynamic>` from which you can retrieve the values.